# How to import a function from a JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Context:** I'm trying to load a distance metric into my webpage that operates within a browser(Firefox). The distance metric is in the form of a javascript function.

**Problem:**
I'm trying to load a function into my webpage through a File Input. However, the JS documentation does not provide a way to import functions within a script. I know that imports should be done from the top of the script, but the script isn't loaded beforehand.

Currently, here's what I have:

```js
$("#param-distance").change(function () {
    $('#div-param-dfunc').toggle($("#param-distance").val()==4);
});

$('#param-dfunc').change(function (){
  var jsFileName = $('#param-dfunc')[0].files[0].name;
  $.getScript(jsFileName).done( function (){
    metric = dMetric; //metric has been defined in the global scope
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="param">
        <label for="param-distance">Distance Metric</label>
        <select id="param-distance" name="param-distance">
            <option value="euclidean" selected="">Euclidean distance</option>
            <option value="manhattan">Manhattan distance</option>
            <option value="jaccard">Jaccard dissimilarity</option>
            <option value="dice">Dice dissimilarity</option>
            <option value=4>Other</option>
        </select>
    <output for="param-distance" id="param-distance-value"></output>
</div>
<div class="param" id="div-param-dfunc" style="display:none">
     <label for="param-dfunc">Distance Metric File</label>
     <input id="param-dfunc" type="file">
     <output for="param-dfunc" id="param-dfunc-value"></output>
</div>
```

Below is the distance metric file:

```js
export default function dMetric(a,b){
    /**
     * Computes a distance between two points.
     * The parameters should have the smae length
     * Note that the distance metric should return a single non-negative value.
     * It should also not return infinity.
     * If the arrays are the same, dMetric should return 0.
     * @param {Array} a
     * @param {Array} b
     * @return {Number} distance
     */
    if(a.length!==b.length){
        throw "The arrays have different lengths";
    }
    //Computation goes here. Store the distance as val.
    var val = Math.abs(a-b);
    return val;
}
```

When I check my Firefox log, I see 2 syntax errors:

```
SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module
ReferenceError: dMetric is not defined
```

I understand that the syntax error is because I tried importing within the script.
Also, the reference error is probably due to the fact that the distance metric was loaded but not run.

I'm open to suggestions.

Lastly, I think PHP might have some sort of capability for this issue, but I would prefer sticking with JavaScript and HTML. Also, I would prefer not to use Node if possible.

Comment: Do you have access to that .js file? in that case, did you try removing `export default` from that file?

Comment: I do have access to the js file. After removing the export default, it works, but I am curious as to why I do not need any export for the function. Are exports used primarily for modules and libraries?

Comment: Well, I guess, the most suitable explanation is: You don't import a complete module (that can't be done by jQuery), but the script is hosted within a module and loading additional code _into that existing module_. So, that additional code must not have an `export`-declaration, because you can't export anything from the already running module anymore.